# Django Forbid HttpResponse

Tags: django, httpresponse

I am working on a tiny movie manager by using the out-of-the-box admin module in Django.

I add a "Play" link on the movie admin page to play the movie, by passing the id of this movie. So the backend is something like this:

```
import subprocess 
def play(request, movie_id):
try:
    m = Movie.objects.get(pk=movie_id)
    subprocess.Popen([PLAYER_PATH, m.path + '/' + m.name])
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/core/movie")
except Movie.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse(u"The movie is not exist！")
```

As the code above reveals, every time I click the "play" link, the page will be refreshed to /admin/core/movie, which is the movie admin page, I just do not want the backend to do this kind of things, because I may use the "Search" functions provided by the admin module, so the URL before clicking on "Play" may be something like: "/admin/core/movie/?q=gun", if that response takes effect, then the query criteria will be removed.

So, my thought is whether I can forbid the HttpResponse, in order to let me stay on the current page.

Any suggestions on this issue ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used the custom action in admin to implement this function.
So finally I felt that actions are something like procedures, which have no return values, and requests are something like methods(views) with return values...

Thanks !